# What is feasibility analysis in thesis proposal?

Tags: thesis

I'm undergraduate student majoring in software engineering, right now I'm preparing my thesis proposal which indicates that one of the chapters should be about "contents and feasibility analysis of the research", I get the content part but what confuses me is the feasibility analysis.
Because the topic I'm doing is defect analysis for a website developed by our college, and I don't have any idea about how a feasibility study about this specific topic could be carried out.

I tried listing some case studies that can be somehow relatable to my defect analysis topic, but I'm not sure whether this is a good approach or not.

Any insights would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feasibility is about whether the research can, in fact, be successfully completed with the time and other resources available. In an undergraduate course, a study requiring three years is infeasible.

If the research suggests building something, feasibility also involves whether it is possible to build such a thing given costs, and even, potentially, the laws of physics.

Another way to look at it for such a course is to ask, is this project actually *do-able* in the timeframe required. And if the answer comes up *no*, then you need to rescale or otherwise modify the proposal.

Comment: Hmm, so what I've understood is that I should focus on the success factors of my project like cost and time. thank you so much that's really narrowed my scope, my thinking was in another universe.